# "Previously" vs. "last time"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

> - This is the vendor from which the item was purchased the last time.
> - This is the vendor from which the item was purchased previously.

Is there a better way to write them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Previously" is more vague than "last time." Last time is a single event, and the most proximate one. Previously can be any time in the past.

In terms of construction, it's passive-voice and can be cleaned up by being more direct:

"I/we purchased [the item] from this vendor last time."

Answer (score 1):

**This is the vendor from which the item was purchased *[the]* last time.**

- (I would omit the indicated ***the***.)
- We purchased from this vendor last time.
- No information about who we purchased from prior to last time: it
  may have been the same vendor; it may have been someone else.

**This is *the* vendor from which the item was purchased previously.**

- Implies that we used this vendor last time and the few times prior to
  that.
- Implies (note: ***the*** vendor) that we have used *only this vendor* (and no others) in at least the recent past.

**This is *a* vendor from which the item was purchased previously.**

- We have used this vendor previously at least once.
- No information about whether we used him last time and/or prior to
  that.
- Implies (note: ***a*** vendor) that we have also used other vendors at times.

Answer (score 0):

A good example of the difference is on TV shows during the recap.  You will usually hear the narrator say "previously on [TV show]" which allows the producers to put in excerpts from more than one episode.  If they said "last time", they would be more limited in what they edit together.